# EF6 not updating, only inserts

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

I have following structure in SQL Server DB

Company -> Branches -> BranchTelephone -> TelephoneNumber

So, Company has many branches which has many telephonenumbers. Branch to TelephoneNumber is Many-To-Many

Here is Entity classes:

```
    public class Company
    {
       public Company()
       {
         this.Branches = new HashSet<Branch>();
       }

       [Key] 
       //identity column in sql server
       public int Id{ get; set; }
       public string Name{ get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches{ get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Branch
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Branch"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public Branch()
        {
            this.TelephoneNumbers = new HashSet<TelephoneNumber>();          
        }

        [Column("BranchID")]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId{ get; set; }

        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TelephoneNumber> TelephoneNumbers { get; set; } 
   }

public partial class TelephoneNumber
{
    public TelephoneNumber()
    {
      this.Branches = new HashSet<Branch>();
    }   

    [Key]
    [Column("TelephoneID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }    
 }
```

I try to do the following to test the setup:

```
var t1 = new TelephoneNumber();
var t2 = new TelephoneNumber();
using(var context = new MyDbContext() )
{
   var company = new Company
   {
     Name = "C1",
     Branches = 
     {
       new Branch
       {
         TelephoneNumbers = {t1, t2}
       }
     }          
   };
   context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

At this point watching SQAl Server Profiler and runnign SQL, all data is
inserted correctly

```
using(var c2 = new MyDbContext())
 {
    var company2 = c2 .Companies.First(x=>x.Name == "C1" );
    var b1 = company2 .Branches.First();

    //data matches what is inserted above

    b1.TelephoneNumbers.Clear();
    b1.TelephoneNumbers.Add(new TelephoneNumber() );

    company2.Name = "Updated";

    c2.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Atfer above save changes followign statements get genrated at sql server

```
1. Update Company set name  = "Updated" -- Correct
2. Delete from BranchTelephone the two entries that were added during first insert
3. Insert New Company
4. Insert new Branch
5. Insert new Telephone Number
6. Insert new Branch Telephone
7. Insert new Telephone Number
8. Insert new Branch Telephone
9. Insert new Telephone Number
10. Insert new Branch Telephone
```

So basically it updates and deletes as expected.

But then go about recreating everything from step one, so that I have total of 3 telephone numbers instead of 1.

I have no idea what is going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

I played around and turns out

everything is fine if I ommit following line:
b1.TelephoneNumbers.Add(new TelephoneNumber() );

By fine I mean it updates data and remove all associated telephone numbers just fine. But, If I do above line in the same context then it forgets about everything else and just inserts everythign new i.e. a new company, branch and 3 telephone numbers (including two deleted ones)

This is just unacceptable. What am I doing wrong here

Comment: You need to mark your child objects as modified. It's a pain. You could also use GraphDiff. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789903/updating-child-entities-in-entity-framework-mvc

Comment: That wast the issue. One of the entities was from a separate instance of db context, hence creating all this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be one entity belonging to a seperate instance of dbcontext. So context1 was used to get an entityA instance, which was added to context2.entityBCollection, causing EF to insert everything, instead of only the instance of entityA.

I think its some sort of bug in EF, because if entityA was not attached to contextB either it should have thrown an exception or only created entityA in the database. But instead, contextB sent inserts for the entire hierarchy of objects that were attached to contextB to the database.